# Terraform : How to grab the properties inside a block from Data Module

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I already have a azure app service plan, from which i want to get the `sku`->`tier` property

```
data "azurerm_app_service_plan" "shared" {
  name                = "SharedMove-AP"
  resource_group_name = "SharedMove-RG"
}
```

[Since SKU itself is a block as defined below](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/app_service_plan#argument-reference)

[image]

How can i get the tier property inside the sku ?

I tried like
`app_service_plan_tier     = "${data.azurerm_app_service_plan.shared.sku.tier}"`

But i got the error like

> This value does not have any attributes.

How can i get the `tier` property inside the `sku` block from data module ?

Comment: Your doc link is to the `resource` instead of the `data`. Otherwise, your namespace is fine as is, so something else is probably going wrong here.

Comment: can you check this link for the [data](https://docs.w3cub.com/terraform/providers/azurerm/d/app_service_plan) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you possibly try

```
data.azurerm_app_service_plan.shared.sku[0].tier
```

Might need to declare the index position.